# A very simple seasonal riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> In rivers as upon your plate,
>
> I hum a tune while you wait.
>
> A snakes tongue licks the devil's tail,
>
> Four times each thrust I will impale.

What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are a

> fork.

In rivers as upon your plate,

> It's cutlery and what happens when a [river splits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_fork).

I hum a tune while you wait,

> A [tuning fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuning_fork) is what you sit still for a moment to listen to while tuning.

A snakes tong licks the devils tail,

> Both snake tongues and imaginary devil tails(?) are forked at the end. (Googling devil pictures, I am less sure about the second part. But they're all imaginary anyway, so why not!)

Four times each thrust I will impale.

> Many (eating and garden) forks have 4 [tines](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tine#Noun). The pitchfork may lend itself to garden work during this season, depending on one's location, which would explain the title as well.